# Rails: List all parent objects whose children have non-NULL value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a parent class `Job` that can have 0 to many `LaserSheets`:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :laser_sheets
  ...
end

class LaserSheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job
  ...
end
```

Currently the `index` action in the `Job` controller returns all `Jobs` with 1 or more `LaserSheets`:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def index
    @jobs = Job.joins(:laser_sheets).uniq.all.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end
  ...
end
```

`LaserSheet` has a datetime attribute `cut_at`. I would like to be able to filter the `Job` results to only show `Jobs` where all `LaserSheets` have non-null `cut_at` attributes.

I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687406/rails-filter-records-of-child-model-based-upon-the-parent-model-attribute) explaining how to filter children based on the parent's attribute, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do to the reverse.

**Edit 2/17/16:**

Per Hieu's recommendation, I tried the following:

```
@jobs = Job.joins(:laser_sheets).where('laser_sheets.id NOT IN (SELECT id 
                                                                FROM laser_sheets 
                                                                WHERE cut_at IS NULL)')
```

It didn't appear to work, so I seeded an empty database with the following test info:

```
Job.create!(id: 1, name: "Job 1")
Job.create!(id: 2, name: "Job 2")
Job.create!(id: 3, name: "Job 3")
LaserSheet.create!(id: 1, name: "1", job_id: 1, cut_at: nil)
LaserSheet.create!(id: 2, name: "2", job_id: 1, cut_at: nil)
LaserSheet.create!(id: 3, name: "3", job_id: 2, cut_at: nil)
LaserSheet.create!(id: 4, name: "4", job_id: 2, cut_at: "2016-02-17 23:00:00")
LaserSheet.create!(id: 5, name: "5", job_id: 3, cut_at: "2016-02-17 23:00:00")
LaserSheet.create!(id: 6, name: "6", job_id: 3, cut_at: "2016-02-17 23:00:00")
```

The correct answer to my question should return only `Job 3`, as that is the only `Job` with all `LaserSheets` having a non-NULL `cut_at`. I ran Hieu's proposed answer:

```
jobs = Job.joins(:laser_sheets).where('laser_sheets.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM laser_sheets WHERE cut_at IS NULL)')

  Job Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" INNER JOIN "laser_sheets" ON "laser_sheets"."job_id" = "jobs"."id" WHERE (laser_sheets.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM laser_sheets WHERE cut_at IS NULL))
```

and it returns both `Job 2` and `Job 3`, which is not what I am looking for.

**Edit 2/19/16:** added cut_at info to test case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This joins laser_sheets to jobs but only where there are no uncut laser_sheets.

```
Job.joins(:laser_sheets).
  where('not exists (select * from laser_sheets as l2 where l2.job_id = jobs.id and l2.cut_at is null)')
```

Running against your data set returns only row 3

Answer (score 0):

> where all LaserSheets have non-null cut_at attributes

Logically, it equals:
`ALL ( LaseerSheet's cut_at IS NOT NULL)` = `NOT ( ANY ( LaseerSheet's cut_at IS NULL ) )`

So the query will be:

```
    @jobs = Job.joins(:laser_sheets).where('laser_sheets.id NOT IN (SELECT id 
                                                                    FROM laser_sheets 
                                                                    WHERE cut_at IS NULL)')
```

Comment: This appears to return Jobs with **at least** one LaserSheet with a non-null cut_at. I am trying to find Jobs where **every** LaserSheet has a non-null cut_at.

Comment: @Ryan: Let check the query again, I used `NOT IN`, not `IN`, so the logic is absolutely correct

Comment: I edited my initial question to include the tests showing why this doesn't work.

Comment: How does `cut_at` attribute assign to `LaserSheet`?